# $page = get_page_by_title CONTAINS

Tags: pages

Just wondering how to fetch a page by using 'title contains'. I can retrieve a page by using the following

```
<?php 
$page = get_page_by_title('Restaurants and Pubs');
?>
```

but how could I do 'page title contains "Pubs"'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a query using the Wordpress database class.  Place this in your functions.php file

```
function get_page_by_title_search($string){
    global $wpdb;
    $title = esc_sql($string);
    if(!$title) return;
    $page = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_title LIKE '%$title%'
        AND post_type = 'page' 
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        LIMIT 1
    ");
    return $page;
}
```

Use this in your theme:

```
$page = get_page_by_title_search('Foo Bar');
echo $page->post_title;
echo $page->post_content;
//etc...
```

Comment: Actually I'm just looking to pull a page into my template. For example, this drags in the 'Restaurants and Pubs' page...

    <?php
      function callpage($page) {
        $my_id = $page;
        $post_id = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
        $content = $post_id['post_content'];
        return $content;
      }
    ?>

    <div id='somediv'>
      <?php

Comment: Then this would be your answer. I updated the answer to show you how to use this.

Comment: Sorry, I only managed to half write my answer, and it won't format my code in the comments (grrr). What I was meant to say is that this works perfectly... http://jsfiddle.net/NnaqM/1/ , but I want to drag in a page by just typing in *pub* i.e. not type out the whole title, so something like this  $page = get_page_by_title(contains 'Pubs');

Comment: When I say 'typing' I mean all in the backend template, nothing to do with the search box in the interface.

Comment: Just make this into a function (see my latest edit). There's no need to use get_post() because the entire post object is returned from the query.

Comment: @BrianFegter Do $page->page_title and $page->page_content really exist, or you would rather need to use $page->post_title and $page->post_content?

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well for me. Would love to hear feedback on better ways to do it though. Thanks!

```
// Get all pages
$my_pages = get_pages();

// Get ID's of pages with "string" in title
foreach ($my_pages as $my_page) {

    if ( stristr($my_page->post_title, 'string') ) {

        $include_ids .= $my_page->ID . ',';

    }

}

// Output only pages with "string" in the title
$args = array(
  'include' => $include_ids,
);

wp_list_pages( $args );
```